# Как мне посчитать аптайм из таблицы?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services

Добрый день - у меня есть такой вопрос
есть таблица со списком

```
id   server_id   time_date            old_status   new_status
100  55          2014-06-03 11:32:36               run
101  55          2014-10-03 10:15:36  run          down
102  55          2014-10-06 10:33:36  down         run 
5604 56          2014-08-04 07:03:26  run          down
```

id - номер события
server_id - имя сервера
time_date - время события
old_status - состояние сервера в предудущем состоянии
new_status - измененное состояние.

Мне нужно знать аптайм сервера.

Comment: *Мне нужно узнать аптайм сервера с учётом состояний.* это как?

Comment: Я не совсем точно выразился - я должен подсчитать время пока сервер был в состоянии run.

Comment: переведите все времена в секунды и из суммы всех даунов вычтите сумму всех апов

Answer (score 1):

### mysql

например, так (под `id` имеется в виду идентификатор сервера):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18232/7)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table vremena (id int, v datetime, s text);

insert into vremena values
  (55, '2014-06-03 11:32:36', 'run'),
  (55, '2014-10-03 10:15:36', 'down'),
  (55, '2014-10-06 10:33:36', 'run'),
  (55, '2014-08-04 07:03:26', 'down');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
  sum(
    case
      when s = 'run' then - unix_timestamp(v) else unix_timestamp(v)
    end
  ) as vremja
from vremena
group by id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18232/7/0)**:

```
|  vremja |
|---------|
| 5080370 |
```

### ms/sql

например, так (под `id` имеется в виду идентификатор сервера):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c825b/3)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
create table vremena (id int, v datetime, s varchar(4));

insert into vremena values
  (55, '2014-06-03 11:32:36', 'run'),
  (55, '2014-10-03 10:15:36', 'down'),
  (55, '2014-10-06 10:33:36', 'run'),
  (55, '2014-08-04 07:03:26', 'down');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
  sum(
    case
      when s = 'run' then - datediff(second, '19700101', v)
      else datediff(second, '19700101', v)
    end
  ) as vremja
from vremena
group by id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c825b/3/0)**:

```
|  vremja |
|---------|
| 5080370 |
```

Comment: а зачем группировать  по id? выкиньте. уж лучше выберите времена для одного сервера

Comment: @splash58, я под id-ом именно сервер и подразумевал. сейчас посмотрел — у автора в таблице тоже id есть. хм, многовато нужно менять «для красоты»: две страницы на sqlfiddle и сам ответ. буду надеяться, что автор разберётся и так.

Comment: ну уж в ответе всяко неприлично так оставлять

Comment: @splash58, а я добавил расшифровку.